# Has anybody used Evrogen's DSN-normalization protocol for cDNA normalization?

Tags: protocol, mrna

I found the link to a commercial product by Evrogen to normalise cDNA samples for gene discovery projects here:
http://www.evrogen.com/technologies/normalization.shtml

The most up-to-date reference seems to be this Curr Protoc Mol Biol. paper by Bogdanova et al.:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20373503

They claim their method is compatible with nextgen sequencing platforms:

> cDNA normalization using duplex-specific nuclease (DSN) is a highly
>   efficient approach that can be applied for normalization of
>   full-length-enriched cDNA (Zhulidov et al., 2004; Zhulidov et al.,
>   2005). The resulting cDNA contains equalized abundance of different
>   transcripts and can be used for construction of cDNA libraries and for
>   direct sequencing, including high-throughput sequencing on the next
>   generation sequencing platforms (Roche/454, ABI/SOLiD or
>   Illumina/Solexa).

Has anybody successfully used it for next-gen gene discovery projects?

Comment: This seems to be more like a poll than a question.

Comment: Can I turn it into a poll in this website?

Comment: No, I meant more that poll-type questions can be closed as "not constructive".  You should probably reword it a bit to prevent this.